# Does anybody encountered an ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR on request to the Here Maps tile server?

Tags: here-api, http2

It happens from the time to time on <s>Chrome-based</s> Chrome-based and Firefox browsers (fully updated versions, clean installs, also in incognito modes), on some (but not all) Windows machines.

Example of called URL is `https://2.base.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/2f447c1cac/normal.day/11/1071/663/256/png8?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=*********&app_code=******&lg=pol&criticality=major%2Ccritical`

The status of the connection is "Pending" (but 200 OK) for 30 secs, then ends with no response (still 200 OK). But the console is reporting `net:ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 OK`.

As a result tiles aren't loaded, map does not work as expected. The license is commercial (not freemium one).

A log from `chrome://net-export/` and parsed by netlog-viewer, contains descriptions like this:

```
https://1.base.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/2f447c1cac/normal.day/11/1075/662/256/png8?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=******&app_code=******&lg=pol&criticality=major%2Ccritical
Start Time: 2019-04-01 14:29:29.999

t=    0 [st=    0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=30043]
                    --> has_upload = false
                    --> is_pending = true
                    --> load_flags = 268452672 (BYPASS_TURBO | DO_NOT_SAVE_COOKIES | DO_NOT_SEND_AUTH_DATA | DO_NOT_SEND_COOKIES | MAYBE_USER_GESTURE)
                    --> load_state = 15 (READING_RESPONSE)
                    --> method = "GET"
                    --> net_error = -1 (ERR_IO_PENDING)
                    --> status = "IO_PENDING"
                    --> url = "https://1.base.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/2f447c1cac/normal.day/11/1075/662/256/png8?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=*****&app_code=*****&lg=pol&criticality=major%2Ccritical"
t=30043 [st=30043]    HTTP2_STREAM_ERROR
                      --> description = "Server reset stream."
                      --> net_error = "ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR"
                      --> stream_id = 1337
t=30043 [st=30043]   -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY
                      --> net_error = -337 (ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR)
t=30043 [st=30043]    FAILED
                      --> net_error = -337 (ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR)
t=30043 [st=30043] -REQUEST_ALIVE
                    --> net_error = -337 (ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR)
```

Comment: Often due to bad HTTP headers. See here: https://www.michalspacek.com/chrome-err_spdy_protocol_error-and-an-invalid-http-header

Comment: Many thanks. This is something else. I've updated my question by including description of tile request.

Comment: Is this issue fixed? If not, then please provide your app_id(only) and the time of the request so that we can check our logs.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Hi. It still exists. APP_ID=C6zYnrV54xOdNAohoaxl, the time of affected requests was around 13:08-13:10 GMT today (Apr 2019, 23), IP 46.170.51.81. Please take a look at pending connections - https://ibb.co/mvZ7zjb

Comment: Since you are in a commercial plan, you can also contact your reseller who can help you directly on this.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Reseller suggested to contact your support team, so we did it. As a result two submitted tickets still have no reply nor solution for a month. In this case contacting the reseller makes no sense. Also, he has no possibility to fix the issue, because it is on the server side / AWS.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport It seems that your's official support died. We still have  no answers nor help for months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by HERE Maps.